# Is there a way to have a settings bundle ONLY in the debug version of my app?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

For production all users of my app will point at the production URL but for dev we have multiple developers and I want to create a settings bundle so the other devs can easily reconfigure their ios devices to point at their own machines. Is there a way to only have the settings bundle in the debug (aka non production) version of the app?

Comment: Have you thought of using version control with a different branch for development which has a different Setting bundle?

Comment: That's definitely an option. Although I would prefer to do something via the Project file rather than the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a wrapper for the NSUserDefaults. In my app delegate I check compiler flags to see if we are in release or debug mode and set the default to the testing vs production environments. Then I use those same compiler flags in my logon view controllers to display/hide a button that allows our test users to select from the different enviroments that are provided via a plist I've included in the build.

So the answer is - Compiler Flags to set the default values, and debug enabled interface prompts to set developer specific values.